# Find out which version of WordPress a blog is using (from outside)

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I want to know if there's a way, not having access to the administration of a blog, to know which version of WP is running under the hood.

Comment: Short of WP embedding version information in a header or somewhere in the body, or probing the site for version-specific bugs/behavior, I doubt it's possible.

Comment: @Marc B thats actually not true.  So says the Blind Elephant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress blogs are typically configured to present the version in a `meta` header, like follows:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.0.5" />
```

Wordpress sites hosted at wordpress.com have:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com" />
```

...and I don't see any version information in their headers.

Answer (score 4):

right click on the page and go to `View Page Source` and check for this meta tag

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.1.2" />
```

the content value defines your wordpress veersion

Answer (score 3):

[Blind-Elephant](http://blindelephant.sourceforge.net/) does web application fingerprinting.  It can detect a version of of the webapp regardless of its version string.  It can also go further and detect installed modules.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fun, heh.

Here are some good points:

1. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-determine-version-of-wordpress

> You can also view the source code of the blog, and often times, but not always, see the version there.

Not sure if you have to be logged in or not to get that. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This site will check to see if Wordpress is installed. It will also give you the version number:- [http://www.isitwp.com/]

I hope this helps.